# Dashboard controls have all stopped working

Tags: jquery, wp-admin, admin, dashboard, jquery-ui

I have an issue with a site where all of the dashboard controls that require javascript are not working. I have checked the console and there are no javascript errors which seems odd. There are also no php errors in the log either. On the main dashboard, all of the following have stopped working

- Draggable widgets
- Mobile menu toggle
- Screen Options dropdown & the help drop down next to it

It seems like jquery-ui has stopped working or something like this, but it only happens on the main dashboard page. All other pages in wp-admin work fine, it is just the main dashboard that this is happening in. I havnt added any new widgets that might cause this so im not quite sure what is going on here. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Start de-activating all your plugins, one by one. Mostly likely there is a conflict produced by a update of a plugin or theme